# Querying sub document Ravendb

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

```
int start = 0;
var current = _db.Query<Record>().Take(1024).Skip(start).ToList();
```

this works fine, a list is returned that contains a list of sub documents/pocos, as shown in the image below :

[image: keyword collection shown]

This shows the Keywords collection, that is a list of keyword pocos. However, I want to return all the keywords, so i tried doing this :

```
int start = 0;
var current = _db.Query<Keyword>().Take(1024).Skip(start).ToList();
```

However nothing gets returned ? All imports ok, everything compiling and running, just nothing listed...

Edit
When implementing a static index and using map/reduce  the follwing segment of code

```
  Map = record => from keyword in record.Keywords 
  // here visual studio doesn't allow subdocuments, 
  // only offers up System.Object methods after record ?
```

Screenshot :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can only query on the *root* documents in RavenDB.
Now, you can query all the root documents that contain a particular value in a child object (*not* a sub document, there is no such thing), but you're still asking for the root document.

For example, a query would look like: Give me all the records that has the keyword "nice" in them:

```
session.Query<Record>().Where(x=>x.Keywords.Contains("Nice")).ToList();
```

And you can ask, from all the records, give me the keywords they have:

```
session.Query<Record>().Select(x=> x.Keywords).ToList();
```

But you are always going from the root doc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query the keywords directly then you could write an index.

```
public class KeywordsIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Record, KeywordsIndex.Result>
{
    public KeywordsIndex()
    {
        Map = records => from record in records
            from keyword in record.Keywords
            select new 
                {
                    Keyword = keyword
                }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public Keyword Keyword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

set it up:

```
documentStore.Initialize();
documentStore.ExecuteIndex(new KeywordsIndex());
```

then call it:

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    session.Query<KeywordsIndex.Result, KeywordsIndex>().Select(r => r.Keyword).ToList();
}
```

This way you can actually query the keywords and sort or filter etc.
See more here on static indexes: http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/static-indexes/defining-static-index

You may be able to return Keyword directly from the index, not sure, but it would prob be nice for you if you could.

Comment: when I do this, visual studio is not allowing me to specifiy a sub-document in the linq expression ? See question edit for more details

Comment: the compiler should get the type from the class - `public class KeywordsIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Record, KeywordsIndex.Result>`. Because then `Map` is a `Func<IEnumerable<Record>, IEnumerable>`, and the compiler can infer from that. Make sure your doing it in the constructor.